# PHP Pull data out of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I know this should be a relatively simple thing but I have not been able to do it yet. I have look hi and low and every example I try it fails I am sure it is fairly simple

Here is my array. I need to get the value of name last and filenames
Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!!

```
Array
(
    [formData] => Array
        (
            [name] => TEST
            [last] => TEST1
            [filenames] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /ocdata/uploads/export-1511887767.csv
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Working with arrays is __php basics__. Read a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) please, everything is described there.

Comment: Are you looking for `$formData['name']` and `$formData['filenames'][0]`?

Comment: $name = $array['formData']['name']; ?

Comment: You looked high and low and couldn't find out how to access an array index?

Comment: @MCMXCII cuz it is in the middle?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Really simple method to see your content:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
   echo $k . $v . PHP_EOL; // see content of your array
}
```

Or use directly the values:

```
$array['formData']['name'];
$array['formData']['last'];
$array['formData']['filenames'];
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question and `Notice: Array to string conversion`

Comment: While this may answer the question in a way, the answer could be majorly improved by showing OP the _proper_ way to do it, vs "just a way". If it generates a notice or an error, it's not the right way. Teach a man to fish and all that....

Comment: Thanks everyone your answer were correct sorry it was a completely different issue that was haunting me. It had nothing to do with the array once I figured it out (i cannot even remember what it was) everything worked fine.

Comment: Well I’m glad I helped anyway.